# SQL: Query to get the last change in value of a specific column

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group, gaps-and-islands

So I have this table of product information. Each time a specific product is changed a new row is inserted with the new values, including time stamp and user who modified it.

To show the information I search for the latest row for a specific product (which is identified by a column which is product_id).

But now I need to know who was the last person that modified one specific column which is named status.

So let's say my table consists of this

So in essence I need to write a query that will tell me when was the last change for that given column.

```
product_id | name | status   | user | keyid
--------------------------------------------
598        | prrr | 0        | john | 10
598        | prod | 1        | jane | 11
456        | abcd | 2        | mac  | 12
598        | prdd | 2        | kate | 13
598        | rdpd | 2        | jane | 14
456        | prrr | 3        | john | 15
456        | abbb | 3        | kate | 16
```

So the latest information for product 598 is

```
598 rdpd 2 jane 14
```

BUT the last person that changed released is kate

The latest information for product 456 is

```
456 abbb 3 kate 16
```

BUT the last person that changed released is john

So Ideally, I would want to write a query that would return

```
598 kate 13
456 john 15
```

I don't even begin to have an Idea on how to write such query, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by productid order by keyid desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(status) over (partition by productid order by keyid) as prev_status
            from t
           ) t
      where prev_status is null or prev_status <> status
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The innermost subquery compares each value to its previous value.  The middle subquery enumerates each row for a product that has a change in status.  The outer query filters to get the latest one.

Comment: I've had question before, where window functions were suggested. However my server DB does not support window functions.

Answer (score 0):

If your database does not support window functions, the logic is a bit more complicated.

As a starter, consider the following query, that gives you the first `idkey`s of rows that have the latest `status` per `product_id`:

```
select product_id, min(keyid)
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.product_id = t.product_id and t1.status <> t.status and t1.keyid > t.keyid
)
group by product_id
```

This returns:

```
product_id | min(keyid)
---------: | ---------:
       598 |         13
       456 |         15
```

You can then use this resultset to filter the table:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.keyid in (
    select min(keyid)
    from mytable t
    where not exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.product_id = t.product_id and t1.status <> t.status and t1.keyid > t.keyid
    )
    group by product_id
)
```

Results:

```
product_id | name | status | user | keyid
---------: | :--- | -----: | :--- | ----:
       598 | prdd |      2 | kate |    13
       456 | prrr |      3 | john |    15
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=617d6be4c0543d907642e73c476dca26)**

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I will be sure to try it out. However I had to solve de problem fast, and since no answer had come, I just ended up modifying the table to it would have more columns to store the data that I needed. But this would have been A LOT more elegant and far easier to implement